# Cobol Filestatus 98

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I am dynamically creating a PS file (based on timestamp from input file) on the Cobol program and using it as output file to write transaction details, but if the input file s received twice, job is failing with duplicate dataset. So I thought of rewrite the file if the file is already allocated. To do this i have tried all these options I-O/Extend/Output to open the output file but it is failing with Filestatus 98

Any idea how can to do this?

```
DISPLAY '5000-B-->'
PERFORM 5000-ALLOCATE-ACK-FILE [ Allocate File Dynamically]
DISPLAY '5000-A-->'
DISPLAY 'I-O--B-->'
OPEN OUTPUT OUT-ACK-FILE
DISPLAY 'WS-OUTACK-STATUS-->' WS-OUTACK-STATUS
DISPLAY 'I-O--A-->'


Error:

ALLOCATE OK 00
5000-A-->
I-O--B-->
IGZ0255W Dynamic allocation failed for ddname OUTACK while processing file OUT-A
         return code from the dynamic allocation was X'4', error code X'FFFFFFFF
         information code X'0'.
WS-OUTACK-STATUS-->98
I-O--A-->
```

Comment: Can you share the code doing the dynamic allocation or is it all in COBOL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't show details of how the allocation is done, or how you check for existence of the data set.

Anyway, on z/OS the `DISP` parameter of the allocation of a PS data set determines whether the data written replaces the current content (if any), or whether it is appended to the current content (if any).

`DISP=NEW` and `DISP=OLD` replace

`DISP=MOD` appends.

The OPEN parameters don't vary.